# Bind data collection on xamarin using mvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, models

So I started learning xamarin and trying different approaches about data binding from the view to the model. I'm retrieving data from a service using post request and after I get the data I can't bind them to the view. After a lot of research I found some interesting solutions and I tried different approaches. 
This what I have achieved until now :
My view :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Ideas.Pages.IdeasSinglePage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Ideas.ViewModel;assembly=Ideas"
          Title="My idea">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:IdeasViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <Button Command="{Binding GetIdeasCommand}"
            Text="Bileta Ime"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="15"
            BackgroundColor="#29abe2"/>
    <Label Text="test"></Label>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Ideas}"
              HasUnevenRows="True">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="20, 10">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding IdeasName}"
                                 FontSize="16"
                               TextColor="RoyalBlue"/>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

This is my viewmodel

```
public class IdeasViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
    public List<Ideas> Ideas
    {
        get { return Ideas; }
        set
        {
            Ideas= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand GetIdeasCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                Ideas= await _apiServices.GetIdeasAsync();
            });
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

This is my service :

```
public async Task<List<Ideas>> GetIdeasAsync()
    {
        ListIdeasDetails ideas= null;
        try { 
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("parameter", "parameter");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("parameter", parameter);

            HttpContent content = new StringContent("");
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://heregoes/themethod", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            ideas= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListIdeasDetails>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return ideas.Ideas;
    }
}
```

And here are my two models :

```
public class Ideas
{

    public string IdeasID  { get; set; }

    public string IdeasName  { get; set; }
 }


class ListIdeasDetails
{
    public List<Ideas> Ideas{ get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public bool HasException { get; set; }

}
```

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks!!

Comment: I would suggest to change the List<ideas> to Observablecollection<Ideas>

Comment: @dilmah I don't think that will change  much. I mean does my code looks ok to you? Or am I missing something? Because I keep getting an empty view after I get the json from the apiservice.

Comment: @Aldo are you sure that your service actually returns any data? Put a break point and see what your web request returns as a first thing. Second, put a a break point in your VM setter of Ideas and see if it ever being called. Off-topic: using POST web request to download data feels like a smell.

Comment: @EvZ ofcourse I'm sure. I already tried that and I receive a json with all the data I need.
I just can't seem to understand as why my view is empty?! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a problem with your [property definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties):

```
 public List<Ideas> Ideas
 {
    get { return Ideas; }
    set
    {
        Ideas= value; // Endless loop
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

Add a backing field this way:

```
List<Ideas> _ideas;
public List<Ideas> Ideas
{
    get { return _ideas; }
    set
    {
        if(value == _ideas) return;
        _ideas = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I would recommend to use [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) in order to reduce the amount of boiler-plate code related to INotifyPropertyChanged. Using Fody your ViewModel will look as simple as:

```
public class IdeasViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
    public List<Ideas> Ideas { get;set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand GetIdeasCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                Ideas= await _apiServices.GetIdeasAsync();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: Beside your main question I would like to point out the next things that does not look good in your code.

1. Using POST to download data from WEB.
2. Class name 'ApiServices'.

You can let me know if you need further assistance by commenting.

Comment: Of course it worked like a charm. I can't believe the mistake I was making. I was always ending in a endless loop. Thanks a lot @evz :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow, please take 1 min to check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The api I'm using only allows post requests. So what can I do in this case?
Whats wrong the class name 'ApiServices'?

Comment: It depends on your context, however, it is common to create a class to define a single object, if you need a collection of objects it is common to use collections. So when you name you class 'ApiServices' in plural it may identify some issues. Are you really defining multiple services within one class? If not, simply rename it to 'ApiService'. Otherwise, you may divide it to separate classes. Regarding the API, if it is written this way and you don't have access to the source code, then you can do nothing about it.

Comment: I have different services in the "ApiServices" class that's why I named it this way. Regarding the api there is nothing I can do about it. 
Can I ask you something? 
Can you please provide me with a solution if on click of the button besides the data I want to navigate to another page and I want to use the data on the other page?! How can I approach to this problem?!
I tried adding  ` Branches = await _apiServices.GetBranchesAsync();
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new TicketSinglePage());` but It doesn't seem to work. 
Thanks in advance @evz

Comment: Please create a separate question if you can't find a solution to you problem.